# How to convert multiple dataframes with string and integer values into a 4D data structure

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a Dataframe called `data1` of the form:

```
ID      y   x  
aa-123  3   4
ca-321  2   2
aa-123  1   3
...    ... ...
```

I would like to convert it into a 3D data structure of the form:

```
['aa-123',
[0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 1 0
 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 1
 0 0 0 0 0]]

['ca-321',
[0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 1 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0]]
```

where y represents row and x represents column for the location of a 1 in a 5x5 matrix.

If ID was an integer then I could do something along the lines of:

```py
3Darray = np.zeros(n_unique_IDs,5,5)
3Darray[data1.iloc[:,0],data1.iloc[:,1],data1.iloc[:,2]]=1
```

However I need to keep ID as a string as data1 is just one channel of 3, so I have another 2 dataframes called data2 and data3 of the above format with different values but the same set of IDs. I need to match IDs for each channel to give a 4D structure `(n_unique_IDs, 5, 5, 3)`.

What would be the best data structure to use? I’m thinking maybe a dictionary but not sure about how to implement?

As a final step, how would I strip out the ID string in the 4D structure so I’m left with just a 4D array of 0s and 1s?

Comment: How large is your dataframe `data1`? I'd have a solution, but it might get bloody if it is huge (but then also your 4D structure is enormous).

Comment: Jottbe, up to around 5000 rows, so (5000,3)

Comment: Ah that's relatively small. I'll try something.

Comment: The IDs in your example should be unique for a given channel, so I guess it's just a typo that aa-123 is doubled.

Comment: Stef, it is not a typo. Each ID could have several x, y values which are used to construct that ID's 0,1 matrix for the channel. Each ID would then have only 1 matrix per channel, so 3 in total.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First we group each dataframe by IDs replacing the individual x and y values by lists of x and y-values. Then we use pandas to [concatenate](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) the three channels into one dataframe, aligning the index (in the example the IDs are in different order in the individual dataframes and the get neatly aligned in the resulting dataframe). This resulting dataframe is shown in the output.
Then we construct our (5,5,3) matrix for each row (taking case of possibley missing IDs in some of the channels) and finally use numpy to [stack](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.stack.html) this all together into on (n,5,5,3) matrix (n=4 in our example):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1 = pd.DataFrame(index=['aa-123','ca-321','aa-123','ab-123','ba-321'], data={'y': [3,2,1,1,4], 'x': [4,2,3,0,1]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame(index=['aa-123','ba-321','ab-123','ca-321'], data={'y': [1,2,3,4], 'x': [1,2,4,3]})
df3 = pd.DataFrame(index=['ca-321','ab-123','ba-321','aa-123'], data={'y': [4,2,0,1], 'x': [1,0,1,4]})

df1 = df1.groupby(level=0).agg({'x':list, 'y':list})
df2 = df2.groupby(level=0).agg({'x':list, 'y':list})
df3 = df3.groupby(level=0).agg({'x':list, 'y':list})

df = pd.concat([df1,df2,df3], axis=1, sort=True)
print(df)

def make_matrix(r):
    m = np.zeros((5,5,3), np.int8)
    try:
        for x,y in zip(r[0],r[1]):
            m[x,y,0] = 1
        for x,y in zip(r[2],r[3]):
            m[x,y,1] = 1
        for x,y in zip(r[4],r[5]):
            m[x,y,2] = 1
    except: # ID is missing for this channel
        pass
    return m

res = np.stack(df.apply(make_matrix, axis=1).to_list())

print(res.shape)
```

Output:

```
             x       y    x    y    x    y
aa-123  [4, 3]  [3, 1]  [1]  [1]  [4]  [1]
ab-123     [0]     [1]  [4]  [3]  [0]  [2]
ba-321     [1]     [4]  [2]  [2]  [1]  [0]
ca-321     [2]     [2]  [3]  [4]  [1]  [4]
(4, 5, 5, 3)
```

If you need to look up the ID for the final 4D array, you'll find it in df.index (e.g. for the `i`th element in `df.index[i]`)

Comment: @CWilliam I updated my answer for multiple IDs per initial dataframe.

Comment: @CWilliam I updated my answer again for the case that not all IDs are present in all three channels (not sure if this is possible, just in case)

Comment: thanks this exactly what I'm after running the toy example. I'm having trouble with the lines e.g. : `df1 = df1.groupby(level=0).agg({'x':list, 'y':list})` as it is converting my integer data into floating point with 1 decimal place, which then can't be used as an index. Any idea why this is happening, or is there a way to force the output of these lines to `int` ?

Comment: This is very strange, as `list` just converts whatever it gets into a list, it doesn't change types. Maybe there is a `Nan` somewhere in your original data that forces this column to `float` type. Just check `df.info()` on all your 3 input channel dataframes to see the types.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another solution.

```
import pandas as pd
import io

# just create example data
raw="""
ID      y   x  
aa-123  3   4
ca-321  2   2
aa-123  1   3
ca-321  2   0
"""

df= pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(raw), sep='\s+')

# create auxillary dataframes to expand the columns (1) and the rows (2)
df_aux_col= pd.DataFrame(list(range(6)), columns=['x'])
df_aux_col[list(range(5))]= pd.get_dummies(df_aux_col['x']).loc[:, list(range(5))]   # by .loc[:, list(range(5))] I just cut off the 6th column produced for x=5 to get a row with all zeros

aux_row_dict= {'y': [], 'y_new': [], 'join': []}
for y_new in range(5):
    for y in range(5):
        aux_row_dict['y'].append(y)
        aux_row_dict['y_new'].append(y_new)
        aux_row_dict['join'].append(y if y==y_new else -1)
df_aux_row= pd.DataFrame(aux_row_dict)

# expand the rows    
df_rows_expanded= df[['ID', 'y', 'x']].merge(df_aux_row, on='y')
# assign 5 to all added rows (5 represents 0 0 0 0 0)
df_rows_expanded.loc[df_rows_expanded['join']<0, 'x']=5

# now expand the columns
df_result= df_rows_expanded.merge(df_aux_col, left_on=['x'], right_on='x', how='left', suffixes=['', '_with_x'])
# aggregate to "combine" rows
df_result= df_result.groupby(['ID', 'y_new'])[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]].agg('max')

# if you want to process the matrices, you can do it as follows
# if you just need them in a list, just add them in the loop body
for group_key, df_group in df_result.groupby('ID'):
    print(f'\n{group_key}:')
    print(df_group)
```

which looks like:

```
aa-123:
              0  1  2  3  4
ID     y_new               
aa-123 0      0  0  0  0  0
       1      0  0  0  1  0
       2      0  0  0  0  0
       3      0  0  0  0  1
       4      0  0  0  0  0

ca-321:
              0  1  2  3  4
ID     y_new               
ca-321 0      0  0  0  0  0
       1      0  0  0  0  0
       2      1  0  1  0  0
       3      0  0  0  0  0
       4      0  0  0  0  0
```

Note, each group is a a dataframe, so you can just put it in your list, or process it directly like above. Btw. with `df_group.values` you get a `numpy.ndarray` with the values. To maintain your list, just execute:

```
[[group_key, df_group.values] for group_key, df_group in df_result.groupby('ID')]
```

The result is:

```
[['aa-123', array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
         [0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
         [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
         [0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
         [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]], dtype=uint8)], ['ca-321', array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
         [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
         [1, 0, 1, 0, 0],
         [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
         [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]], dtype=uint8)]]
```

You might have noticed the second point I inserted for "ca-321", which is not present in your data. This was just to test, that the transformation also works for several points in the same row.